# Expanded wrappers in "All sites" page overflow to the right

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, stackexchange.com

Navigating the ["All sites"](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page, with my browser maximized at my 1280x1024 px screen (this is not critical - the point is the full contents just fit the viewport, no horizontal scroll bar visible), when one clicks on the rounded rectangles (collapsed wrappers) on the right border, they expand towards the right, which is not very satisfactory.

See screenshots, before and after clicking over *"User experience"* site.

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a design bug, but anyway.